# How to avoid double backslashes in string literals being replaced with single backslash?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, replace, backslash

Python string replaces double backslash with a single backslash? How avoid replace? I need to keep `\\n` as it is.

Code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    str1 = '{"en":"M  L\\n\\nL\\n\\nS","fr":""}'
    print(str1)
    print("{}".format(str1))
```

Output:

```
 {"en":"M  L\n\nL\n\nS","fr":""}
 {"en":"M  L\n\nL\n\nS","fr":""}
```

Expected output:

```
 {"en":"M  L\\n\\nL\\n\\nS","fr":""}
```

Comment: You can use raw strings: `r"M  L\\n\\nL\\n\\nS"`

Comment: the input I receive from JSON is `\\n`

Comment: The json you are receiving is a single backslash followed by an `n`. The backslash is escaped, otherwise it would be a newline character. In other words, your json does not have two backslashes, "\\" is a single character in the same way "\n" is a single character.

Answer (score 1):

Use raw strings by inputting an r before the string:

`r"M  L\\n\\nL\\n\\nS"`

This will ignore any and all escape characters.

Read more here: [Raw Strings in Python](https://www.journaldev.com/23598/python-raw-string)

Comment: Oops, duplicated

Answer (score 1):

If you want to tell python to not convert `\\` to `\` you can specify your string as `raw string`. This will auto escape `\` so they will be seen as they are. A raw string is a string that no characters can be escaped in it. You can do this by putting a `r` char before the string starts:

```sh
r"M  L\\n\\nL\\n\\nS"

>>> "M  L\\\\n\\\\nL\\\\n\\\\nS"
```

So you can see that python automatically escaped all the \ characters so when you use this string it will interpret as `"M  L\\n\\nL\\n\\nS"`.

If you have a multi line string you can do this the same way:

```
a = r"""abcdefg\n\t\a
dygkcy\d\wscd"""
```

note: There is no difference for `'` and `"`.